# jekyll 3.1.6 | Error: uninitialized constant Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters

Tags: ruby, jekyll

Hello Jekyll support users

I need serve this repository on Jekyll, but I has this error on Ubuntu 17.04 Terminal

```
geraldo@geraldo-Dell-System-XPS-L322X:~/Documentos/activate.mozilla.community$ bundle exec jekyll serve --config ./_config-dev.yml
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop::NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/document_drop.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NESTED_OBJECT_FIELD_BLACKLIST was here
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.4.3/lib/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: already initialized constant Jekyll::Drops::Drop::NON_CONTENT_METHODS
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/jekyll/drops/drop.rb:8: warning: previous definition of NON_CONTENT_METHODS was here
Configuration file: ./_config-dev.yml
Configuration file: ./_config-dev.yml
jekyll 3.1.6 | Error:  uninitialized constant Jekyll::Filters::URLFilters
```

Anyone here to help me?

Answer (score 16):

I had this problem and it turned out to be that I was using Jekyll from Ubuntu (giving version 3.1.6, as you have) instead of a recent one (such as 3.6.2).  Removing jekyll with:

```
sudo apt-get remove jekyll
```

and then strictly using bundle cleared things up.  Also maybe try `bundle update`.

Comment: This was a good start for me. I then got FATAL: "Listen error: unable to monitor directories for changes.", so I tried `bundle update`. Now I get "Liquid Exception: uninitialized constant Kramdown::Utils::OrderedHash in /_layouts/blog.html".

Comment: FWIW I'm still getting this error after removing jekyll manually and letting bundle handle it all.